# Sudo apt-get update command to restore my Ubuntu 22.04 system cannot acces the nl.ubuntu.com archives on either system of Network

Tags: boot, networking, updates

Trying to reboot my failed Ubuntu 22.04 system failed in recovery mode. Trying to update the kernel with the sudo apt-get update command fails because it could not access the required files in the system of via the Network. Tried every suggested solution to get names resolved. All failed. In recovery mode the system ultimately indicates there is no graphic resolution and continuing down that path i AM forced to get to a terminal command screen and try to reboot, or update ubuntu, without resolve.
I seem Lost in An Ubuntu maze!

---

I have no Networking at all. Trying to restart NetworkManager only gives faults. There must be something wrong with the system not able to find the Configuratieonderdelen files, etc.

Comment: Do you have networking at all (`ip a` shows your ipv4 address, `ping 8.8.8.8` works) and just resolv is broken? You can hand write a resolv.conf or hosts file to get out of that.

Comment: Rather than describe the problem in vague terms, show us the problem: Copy and paste actual input and output into your Question. If you cannot reach a desktop, then post a clear, readable image of the real input and output.

Comment: When replying to comments, use the comment system to reply, don't post answers to reply to comments.  When adding information, simply edit your question.